# AngularJs/Ajax index is changing when i do a loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, loops

I have an array that's created from 2 ajax requests.

```
var myId = 13;

var array = [];

var checkIFfollowing = function(id, username){

UserService.checkIfFollowing(id, myId)
  .success(function (data) {        
    var post = {
      is_following : data, //boolean
      username : username
    }

   array.push(post);
          }).
        error(function(error) {
        //error
      });
}

UserService.GetUserById(user_id)
  .success(function (data) { 
     angular.forEach(data, function(post){    
     checkIfFollowing(post.id, post.username)
           })
          }).
        error(function(error) {
        //error
      });
```

data structure is always returned liked this:

```
[{id:1, username:'ed'},{id:2, username:'joe'},{id:3, username:'bob'}]
```

but after the loop the indexes change, but alot of times it's they are all the same index. Is there a way to make it consistent all the time

Answer (score 0):

You second UserService.checkIffollowing() returns the result asynchronously so the order which array is populated will get change. An efficient way to do thi is maintain an index and sort the array by the index after all the items processed. Sample code as below:

```
var myId = 13;
var array = [];
var dataLength;

var checkIFfollowing = function (index, id, username) {
    UserService.checkIfFollowing(id, myId)
      .success(function (data) {
          var post = {
              is_following: data, //boolean
              username: username,
              index: index
          }

          array.push(post);
          if (dataLength - 1 === index) {
              array.sort(function (a, b) { return a.index - b.index })
          }
      }).error(function (error) {
          //error
      });
}

UserService.GetUserById(user_id)
  .success(function (data) {
      dataLength = data.length;
      data.forEach(function (post, index) {
          checkIfFollowing(index, post.id, post.username)
      })
  }).error(function (error) {
      //error
  });
```